# What is the grammatical rule of " fainting" in this text?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Julian, grasping the head of the weapon, attempted to draw it forth, but in vain – the sharp steel cut his fingers, and the pain and loss of blood caused him to fall fainting from his steed.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score 2):

**Fainting** tells us more about how and why Julian falls from his horse. So it is a participle used as an adverb modifying **caused him to fall**.

It's a construction that English speakers use all the time:

> The dog came **panting** into the house
> The girl ran **yelling** out of the room.
> The hounds streaked **baying** after the fox.

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/119710-participle-as-adverb